# Replacing ACE with BOOST

Tags: c++, boost, ace

I am new to `BOOST`

We are planning to move from `ACE` to `BOOST`. We are not using complete `ACE` but just part of the `ACE` library and some are mentioned below

1. ACE_THREAD
2. ACE_OS
3. ACE_Condition
4. ACE_Timer
5. ACE_Hash
6. ACE_Semaphore
7. ACE_Time_Value

Is this or similar `functionality/api` available in `BOOST` .  Most Important is there `ACE_Task_Base` kind of functionality in `BOOST`

I want to know is this possible using `BOOST` and any problem of using `BOOST`. My Product is pure `C++`, heavy `Network` and `Threads` on `Windows` and `Unices`

Comment: I sense a world of pain coming your way - ACE_Task_Base provides Message and Thread function/interface as I remember. Not sure boost has this level of stuff - it has things you can use to build that function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> **ACE_Semaphore & ACE_THREAD & ACE_Condition**

The above are all part of `boost::threads`

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/thread.html

C++11
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread

> **ACE_OS**

Some common things are done in boost w.r.t. OS but it depends on what parts of this you are using. There is `boost::system` and `boost::filesystem`, threading above and many more. Some of the lower level calls you'll need to handle I suspect.

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/libs/system/doc/index.html

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/libs/filesystem/doc/index.htm

> **ACE_Timer**

`boost::asio` can be used to create timers which are similar to this and this lib may provide more of the function of ACE (or the mechanisms to create it)

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/boost_asio.html

> **ACE_Hash**

ACE_Hash - again there is a lot of function here, but it could be replaced/implemented with boost or C++11

Boost:
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/hash.html

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/unordered.html

c++11:
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map

> **ACE_Task_Base**

I would suspect you'll need to create your own replacement for the functionality here. The messages and message parsing mechanisms are quite involved in ACE. Threading is covered above, but a manager for created threads again is likely to need implementing.